# Python create dynamic/loop based on variables and CSV

Tags: python, file, csv

How do I fix this code to response dynamically to multiple entries (any number of keywords and cvs files) as [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41081800/python-pandas-how-to-use-dataframe-cell-to-search-another-dataframe-column-and)?

It is a Python 2.x script that works for 2 keywords located in **keywords.txt** and 2 CSV files as seen opened withing the code.

```
import csv
from itertools import chain


with open("keywords.txt", "rb") as keywords, open('folding umbrella-sort-highest.csv', 'rb') as g, open('lego minecraft-sort-highest.csv', 'rb') as f, open('filename1.csv', 'wb') as myfile1, open('filename2.csv', 'wb') as myfile2:

# Step1: Read contents of keywords.tex in variables
    ky = list(keywords.readlines())
    ky1, ky2 = ky[0], ky[1]

# Step2: Read and process folding umbrella-sort-highest.csv
    reader = csv.reader(g)
    umbrella_list = list(reader)
    list1 = filter(lambda e: e[0] in ky1, umbrella_list)

    list2 = list(chain(*list1))
    # or better: (available since Python 2.6)
    # print list(chain.from_iterable(list1))

    ind_prt1 = umbrella_list.index(list2) +1 
    mylist1 = umbrella_list[:ind_prt1]

    for r in mylist1:
        wr = csv.writer(myfile1, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        wr.writerow(r)

# Step3: Read and process lego minecraft-sort-highest.csv
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    minecraft_list = list(reader)
    list3 = filter(lambda e: e[0] in ky2, minecraft_list)

    list4 = list(chain(*list3))
    # or better: (available since Python 2.6)
    # print list(chain.from_iterable(list4))

    ind_prt2 = minecraft_list.index(list4) +1 
    mylist2 = minecraft_list[:ind_prt2]

    for r in mylist2:
        wr = csv.writer(myfile2, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        wr.writerow(r)

print "Task completed, check your working directory."
```

The code above works for 2 keywords located in **keywords.txt** and 2 CSV files as seen. I want it to be dynamic to handle any numbers of keywords and CSV file?

Comment: use `for x in ky:` instead of `ky1 = ky[0]  ky2 =ky[1]`

Comment: you don't have to open all files at the same line. you can use `for name in (folding umbrella-sort-highest.csv', 'lego minecraft-sort-highest.cvs'):` and work with one file.

Comment: ok, thanks for stopping by. Can you kindly edit the code to satisfy my request?

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it but it can be

```
import csv
from itertools import chain
import glob

# --- read keywords ----

with open("keywords.txt", "rb") as keywords:
    # remove '\n'
    all_keys = [x.strip() for x in keywords] 

# --- ---

#all_filenames = [
#    'folding umbrella-sort-highest.csv',
#    'lego minecraft-sort-highest.csv',
#]

all_filenames = glob.glob('csv/*.csv')

print all_filenames

# get pair: one key and one filename + current index/number
for idx, (key, input_name) in enumerate(zip(all_keys, all_filenames), 1):

    print idx, key, input_name

    # - read all data from input file -

    with open(input_name, 'rb') as f_in:
        reader = csv.reader(f_in)
        data = list(reader)

    # - change data -

    sublist = filter(lambda e: e[0] in key, data)

    sublist = list(chain(*sublist))
    # or better: (available since Python 2.6)
    # print list(chain.from_iterable(sublist))

    idx_prt = data.index(sublist)+1 
    output = data[:idx_prt]

    # - write all data to output file -

    output_name = 'filename{}.csv'.format(idx)

    with open(output_name, 'wb') as f_out:
        writer = csv.writer(f_out, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        writer.writerows(output)

# --- the end ---

print "Task completed, check your working directory."
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. However, I want it to work dynamically for multiple keywords and csv file. So I tried this { import glob as gb
all_filenames = gb.glob("csv\\*.csv") }. But that didn't work, how do I modify the script to dynamically accommodate multiple keywords and csv file.

Comment: try `/` instead of \ - `"csv/*.csv"`

Comment: Both / and \ are ok. But what am talking about is that I have more than just two CSVs at that location. How do I modify the script to dynamically accommodate multiple csv file.

Comment: That is to say the 1st keywords will look into the 1st CSV, the 2nd keywords will look into the 2nd CSV, the 3rd keywords will look into the 3rd CSV, the 4th keywords will look into the 4th CSV and sooooo on...

Comment: you don't have to change code. If you assign filenames to `all_filenames` (for example using `all_filenames = gb.glob("csv\*.csv")`) then it will work as you need. If something doesn't work then - first: run in console and maybe you will see some error message, second: use `print()` to check what you have in `all_filenames` and other variables.

Comment: Well I tried the modified version but I got this error: ***ValueError: ['lego minecraft the first night', '353600', 'lego minecraft', '1815000', 'lego minecraft the first', '1'] is not in list*** The sample csv/keywords file is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/o02hziehlmg714v/pandas%20task.zip?dl=0

Comment: I tried code and modifications works. Problem is old part of code `filter()`, `chain()`, `index()`. I don't know what you try to do in this code but you have to rethink it. You can use `print()` to check what you have in variables - probably you have not what you expect.